# Looking for the title of a short story about the five senses and god

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the author and title of a story from an anthology, possibly edited by Ben Bova, somewhere between 1979 and 1984.

It was about an astronaut returning to earth having lost his hearing (I think) after encountering some kind of entity he associated with god. The other members of his crew had all lost the use of one of their senses. The one who lost his hearing only heard an odd static noise, again somehow how associated with a god. The one who lost his sight saw only a bright white light. I never got to finish reading it because, for some stupid reason, I didn't check the book out from the library right then.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: And the one who lost his sense of humor just downvoted your question!

Comment: I have read this...maybe a female author? It's actually a good description of the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*(The) Field of Vision*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58827) by Ursula K. Le Guin.

It's a three-man trip to Mars, the crew discovers some kind of alien artifact or city.  When the capsule lands back on Earth, one crew member is found dead, one has his sense of hearing overridden, the other his vision.  The hearing-affected one is cured, the vision-affected one kills himself in the end.

The story ends with another crew returning from Mars, bringing back artifacts and information which are implied to convert the whole Earth to a new religion.

I have it in [The Best from Galaxy Volume II](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35725) which is edited by "the editors of Galaxy", which may well have been Ben Bova.

I consider it kind of an atypical story for Le Guin, being a near-future space exploration kind of story.  I had never heard of it until I acquired this old paperback.

[image]

EDIT: Who knew? It was made into a short film.

[*The Field of Vision*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3noUznJ4-8)